# Нужна ли запятая? Правильно ли построены фразы?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Посмотри, какое бывает молоко. Кто его нам даёт() и из чего его получают.

Comment: Предложения вопросительные, хотя знака вопроса нет, значит, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Неясно, почему вы из одного предложения сделали два, но это допустимо, если на то воля автора.

**Запятая во втором предложении не нужна**. Как указала Людмила, это предложение построено как вопросительные, хотя знака вопроса и нет. Запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения выражены двумя вопросительными, или двумя восклицательными, или двумя побудительными предложениями (см: [Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении](http://lingvotech.com/znakssp))

Можно рассуждать и по-другому, но вывод будет тот же: запятая перед *и* не нужна. А именно, можно считать второе предложение так называмой присоединительной конструкцией, причем наша конструкция выполняет роль членов, однородных с имеющимся в основном высказывании. ([См. 90.2.Бессоюзные присоединительные конструкции](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm)). Можно мысленно присоединить оторванную часть, получится: "Посмотри, какое бывает молоко, кто его нам даёт и из чего его получают." В этом случае имеем три однородных придаточных (Схема: Главное, П1, П2 и П3). Запятая перед *и* не нужна.

Comment: Это подпись к рисунку. Написованы виды молока (напр. корова-коровье, коза-козье и тд; миндаль-миндальное,кокос-кокосовое и тд). Внизу вот такая подпись (это детская книга). Вы считаете, что лучше не делать разбивку на 2 предложения, а сделать так:

Comment: Если вы подразумеваете вопрос, адресованный ребенку, то поставьте знак вопроса во втором предложении. Если нет, то  лучше дать все это одним предложением.

Comment: Спасибо,поправлю.